# Flash as3 webservice call not called, with IE7

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer-7

In a big as3 project we use web service calls with "Operation" class.
There is a webservicecaller class which is used by lots of objects to do calls.

In IE7 (some users, independent of the version), the first call is done, but not the second.

Tracing with MonsterDebugger show us that the function of the webservice is call, but no network traffic is visible in WireShark, and no call is visible serverside, in the server logs.

On my test computer, XP Pro SP3 with IE7, shockwave player 11 installed.

All is fine with other browsers/versions

Is there some specific code to do?

I have added the removeEventListener when the first call is finished, but no changes

Thank you for your help,

Sincerely,

François D

Comment: If you could show some code perhaps?

Comment: is it possible to get this behavior in IE9 with enabled activex filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Prob. ie caches your requests, this may cause the problem. You can use timestamp to solve problem.